# FB Pixel Purchase Event - Working on desktop not on mobile?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-pixel

FB Pixel on desktop firing fine passing order id, revenue etc
Not firing on mobile?
Am seeing the tag firing in GTM preview but getting error message in pixel helper on mob:
WARNINGS
We detected event code but the pixel has not activated for this event, so no information was sent to Facebook. This could be due to an error in the code, but could also occur if the pixel fires on a dynamic event such as a button click.Learn more

Any ideas why this would work fine on desktop but not on mob?

Thanks.

```js
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
 jQuery(document).ready(function()
 { 
  var purchaseLength = {{transactionQty}};
  var purchaseID = [];
  var productName = [];
  var i;
  for(i = 0; i< purchaseLength; i++)
  {
    
    purchaseID.push({{transactionProducts}}[i].sku);
    productName.push({{transactionProducts}}[i].name);

  }
  
    fbq('track', 'Purchase', {
      content_ids: purchaseID,
      content_name: productName,
      content_type: 'product',
      value: {{transactionTotal}},
      currency: 'GBP'
    });
     });  
</script>
```

Comment: Have you checked for script errors? Have you verified code execution get this far?

Comment: Script runs fine on desktop, fires through the relevant values, finding it difficult to troubleshoot on mobile, the Page View tag that also runs on this page is showing:
Facebook Pixel took 6763 milliseconds (6.76 seconds) to load, so some actions may not be tracked.
So wondering if it's a problem with the load?